# Why when one of MongoDB replica set shard members goes offline, the others CPU`s spike to 100%?

Tags: mongodb, performance, cpu-usage, high-availability, replicaset

Powering off one of mongodb Shard members cause the others cpu`s to raise for 100%.

**Background:**
I want to deploy an mongodb cluster on several ESXes. The cluster have to resist two component shutdown.

**Cluster Architecture:**
Mongo 4.2

- 5 config servers
- 3 query servers
- shard01:

  - primary
  - 2 secondary
  - 2 arbiter
- shard02:

  - primary
  - 2 secondary
  - 2 arbiter

**The problem:**

Whenever I have been testing HA by removing one of the members. I noticed, **after several minutes**, that the rest of the members face to CPU spike to 100% which remains until I returned the missing member.

**Tests I have been conducted:**

1. shutdown 1 replica -> members CPU raise to 100%
2. shutdown 1 replica and 1 arbiter -> members CPU raise to 100%
3. shutdown 1 arbiter -> members are OK

**Things i have already checked:**

- When checking the problematic VMs I noticed that the mongod is the
  service which consume most of the CPU (99%).
- I checked mongod for long run-time queries with `db.currentOp()`. Everything looks just fine.
- Mongod.log does not contain any suspicious logs.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in mongod. [Report](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/wiki/Submit-Bug-Reports) it.

Answer (score 0):

You should disable your replica read concern "majority".
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/read-concern-majority/#disable-read-concern-majority